# How to write an api class in JS and call Vuex for change state

Tags: javascript, api, class, vue.js, vuex

I need to write an api class in Javascript and change the Vuex state from the api class.
This is the store.js file (vuex)
Actions that need to be written in different classes for api call is: `getCurrentWeatherData()`, and `getDailyWeatherData()`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import plugins from "../../plugins/plugins";
import Axios from "axios";
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    city: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("location") || " "),
    currentWeatherData: [],
    dailyWeatherData: []
  },
  getters: {
    getIcon(state) {
      let icon = state.currentWeatherData.weather.icon;
      return "https://www.weatherbit.io/static/img/icons/" + icon + ".png";
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    updateCity(state, city) {
      state.city = city;
    },

    setCurrentWeatherData(state, currentWeatherData) {
      state.currentWeatherData = currentWeatherData;
    },
    setDailyWeatherData(state, dailyWeatherData) {
      state.dailyWeatherData = dailyWeatherData;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getCurrentWeatherData({commit}) {
      let url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current",
        key = "key=d278d8fd45ac4a779a5949bd6ee4f37e";
      Axios.get(url + "?" + key + "&" + "city=" + this.state.city)
        .then(res => {
          commit("setCurrentWeatherData", res.data.data[0]);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
    getDailyWeatherData({commit}) {
      let url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily",
        key = "key=d278d8fd45ac4a779a5949bd6ee4f37e",
        days = "days=" + 3;
      Axios.get(url + "?" + key + "&" + days + "&" + "city=" + this.state.city)
        .then(res => {
          commit("setDailyWeatherData", res.data.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    }
  },
  plugins
})
export default store
```

Any help is appreciated, and thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You should be able to just import your store into your class and then just call `store.dispatch('getCurrentWeatherData');` for actions and `store.commit('');` for mutations. Taken directly from Vuex docs here : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 1):

**How to use Vuex outside of the Vue instance ( e.g. `Vue.use(Vuex)` ) :**

Taken from the official Vuex guide https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/ the following should work. Adapt to your need.

```js
/* apiclass.js */

import Store from './store'; /* or wherever your store file is located */ 

class ApiClass { 
   constructor() { 
      // ...
   } 
   storeActionDispatch() { 
      Store.dispatch('getCurrentWeatherData');
   } 
} 

export default ApiClass;
```

```js
/* example.js */

import ApiClass from './apiclass';
const api = new ApiClass();
api.storeActionDispatch(); // This will trigger the Vuex Action
```